# Trying to connect a .php page to a socket server running on a different port than the PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I am working on a website that runs .php files. However, because I test the site through 'localhost' and the specified PHP port (example http://localhost:3000/, I cannot access the socket I created on another port. So if the socket is running on port 8500, when I launch the .php webpage (using Brackets and MAMP), I cannot figure out a way to connect to the socket on port 8500 since I am already on http://localhost:3000/. How can I connect to the socket but remain on the .php page I am currently on?

main_game.php JavaScript:

```
<script src="main_game.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            //$('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg)); For later
        });
    });
</script>
```

There is PHP at the top of the page to save session data so I cannot change the filetype to .html. The socket is listening on port 8501, but the .php is running on localhost:8500

NodeJS script:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('/Users/path.../main_game.php');
});

http.listen(8501, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:8501');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: The socket is socket.io by the way

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser's console? Have you included the socket.io.js script in the page? (I don't see it in the code, but maybe is it included before). If you have any error always share it too in the question (don't forget to anonymize any thing you want to hide, such as personal information, links/addresses you don't want us to see, etc from the logs)

Comment: No error because the socket is not connecting to the server.

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as "a php page" once it's in the user's browser. PHP is only relevant on the server, it generates the page code when the browser requests that page. After that, there is no PHP. It already did its job and the process servicing the page request died, as intended, by design. As for the code you're showing: you're missing the URL in your [var socket = io(url)](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io-url-options) code. Without telling socket.io which URL to connect to for websocket messaging, nothing's going to happen.